# Why have the pronunciations of some foreign words been eschewed during the process of induction into English?

Tags: pronunciation, loanwords

Some foreign-language words were reasonably naturalised to preserve pronunciation — e.g. *cañón* from Spanish to *canyon* in English. Other words came into English retaining their original spelling *and* pronunciation — e.g. *noir* from French. However, it quickly becomes clear that for other (similar) words different conventions have been employed — e.g. *guillotine* is spelt the same in French as in English, but the English cognate is pronounced very differently.

Is there any reason for this? Could any such reasoning be additionally applied to derivations like English *together* from Old English *tōgædere*?

Comment: The phrase 'film noir'  is a 20th century import to English (and derivations such as 'scandi-noir' even more recent). Many foreign imports have been in use much longer and I suppose have had more time to evolve an anglicised pronunciation.

Comment: I am going to put on my 'thinking chapeu" and do my best with this interesting and challenging question. Stay tuned.

Comment: One factor is the struggle most English speakers have with some pronunciations, including words with gutturals and rolling Rs. For instance, the South African word "apartheid" was widely pronounced APART-HIDE by non South Africans. In South Africa it was APARRT-HATE (rolling R) (In Afrikaans "ei" is pronounced "a" as in hay; a final "d" is often pronounced as a "t" - as in "asked".)

Comment: @RonaldSole Please use clear [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) not "spelling pronunciations" when discussing how things are said.

Comment: I have a related factoid that's not quite an answer. The French word "chef" was imported into English twice: the first time it became the word "chief" and the second time it became the word "chef". Words imported longer ago will have changed more.

Comment: Many foreign words were imported into English not by people who spoke those foreign languages, but by people reading books that contained the words.  Since they had no guide as to the pronunciations, they interpreted the spellings using standard English phonetics, perhaps "Frencifying" an ending here and there but otherwise with no comprehension of the "correct" pronunciation.

Comment: @tchrist - The "spelling pronunciations" can be appreciated by virtually all readers here, while IPA is unintelligible to at least half.

Comment: @PeterPoint How goeth thee, sire?

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, isn't the beginning of the word _chandelier_ pronounced in much more of a French way than the rest of the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this varies almost with each word you look at, and many books have been written on the study of etymology.

Much of the etymology of words is migration or conquest-based (there's a lot of French words in English), or older from common root languages (Germanic, Latin).  Some words have entered our vocabulary later than others - the newr ones tending to be less changes.  Over longer periods of time, spellings and pronunciations evolve, change, get mistaken, and otherwise end up in common usage in their current state.

Comment: Yes. What the common pronunciation _is_ is even unclear sometimes, and may differ depending on the accent of the speaker.